# Can object's fields be cached by JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
private final Point p;
void synchronized setPoint(int x, int y) {
    p.x=x;
    p.y=y;
}
Point getPoint() {
    return p;
}
```

Let's say some class A has final reference field Point p.

- The Point p object is created in class A constructor.
- The class A needs to be thread-safe, so there is synchronized setter setPoint which changes p's inner fields.

Since reference p is final, we don't need to bother about reading the reference itself in multithreading environment. But what about the object's inner data?

Can JVM store p's inner data in cache for any running thread?

And in general, does JVM store data from heap (not from stacks) to caches? If so, how should be such fields treated, as volatile keyword affects only reference itself and not referenced object? Or is it OK to left getter and it has no visibility problems?

[image: JVM confusing schema on this topic]

Comment: Quick answer:   Use synchronized when reading the data too.. only synchronizing on the set will cause threading bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are a bit too general.
What JVM? There are a lot of them, with a lot of different versions, too.

I'm familiar with HotSpot and OpenJDK JVMs (I've read big portions of their code), and none of them will bother to "cache" objects, because most of the popular CPUs themselves already do it more efficiently.

If you read from or write to any shared data from different threads, synchronize that field (or fields) with `synchronized` keyword. It will ensure visibility and proper memory ordering.